# Using OAuth Airflow helm

Tags: flask, airflow, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement OAuth with Airflow and my webserconfig.py is as follows as per the [docs](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/security.html#authentication-oauth) for OAuth:

```
    import os
    from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH

    # set OAuth as authentication method
    AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

    # max idle time
    PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = 1800

    OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
        {
            "name": "google",
            "icon": "fa-google",
            "token_key": "access_token",
            "remote_app": {
                "client_id": os.getenv('AIRFLOW__GOOGLE__CLIENT_ID'),
                "client_secret": os.getenv('AIRFLOW__GOOGLE__CLIENT_SECRET'),
                "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
                "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
                "request_token_url": None,
                "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs",
            },
        },
    ]
```

Even tough the OAuth works as expected, I can't set any default to be set.
I've tried JMESPATH as [mechanism](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/config.html#using-jmespath-to-map-user-registration-role) and also setting the AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION to True and the AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE to 'Viewer'.

I've also tried to implement a custom class for the OAuth, as described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/security/webserver.html#example-using-team-based-authorization-with-github-oauth), but it doesn't work.

Has anyone come accross this and could help me ?